# How to overlay one video on another in iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, crop, video-processing

I am trying to crop an already taken video into a circle in iOS. How might I go about doing this. I know how I would do it with AVCaptureSession but I don't know to pass in an already taken video as an AVCaptureDevice? Is there a way to crop a video into a circle. I want to overlay it on top of another video so it has to have a transparent background as well. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to generate a file containing the cropped video, or do you just want to display it live on the screen clipped to a circle?

Comment: I have two videos, and I want to put the circle video on top of the other videos where the circle video is transparent.

Comment: But do you want to write the combined image to a file, or just display it on the screen?

Comment: It is a video. I want to crop a video into a circle and put that video on top of another video. The video doesn't save transparency so I don't know how to combine these two videos. I want to then save the video

Comment: @BlaneTownsend any chance you could help me through the code rob posted, Ive been trying to make some changes for what I want but can't quite get it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you want to produce something like this:

[image: demo of video overlay with oval crop]

You don't want an `AVCaptureSession`, because you're not capturing video.  You want an `AVMutableComposition`. You need to read the [“Editing” section of the *AV Foundation Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1).  Here's a summary of what you need to do:

1. Create the `AVAsset` objects for your videos and wait for them to load their tracks.
2. Create an `AVMutableComposition`.
3. Add a separate `AVMutableCompositionTrack` to the composition for each of the input videos.  Make sure to assign explicit, different track IDs to each track.  If you let the system pick, it will use track ID 1 for each and you won't be able to access both later in the compositor.
4. Create an `AVMutableVideoComposition`.
5. Create an `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`.
6. For each input video, create an `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` and explicitly assign the track IDs you used back in step 3.
7. Set the `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`'s `layerInstructions` to the two layer instructions you created in step 6.
8. Set the `AVMutableVideoComposition`'s `instructions` to the instruction you created in step 5.
9. Create a class that implements the `AVVideoCompositing` protocol. Set the `customVideoCompositorClass` of the video composition (created in step 4) to this custom class (e.g. `videoComposition.customVideoCompositorClass = [CustomVideoCompositor class];`).
10. In your custom compositor, get the input pixel buffers from the `AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest` and use them to draw the composite frame (containing a background video frame overlaid by a circular chunk of the foreground video frame).  You can do this however you want.  I did it using Core Graphics because that's easy, but you'll probably want to use OpenGL (or maybe Metal) for efficiency in a production app.  Be sure to specify `kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey` if you go with OpenGL.
11. Create an `AVAssetExportSession` using your composition from step 1.
12. Set the session's output URL and file type.
13. Set the session's `videoComposition` to the video composition from step 4.
14. Tell the session to `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:`.  It will probably be slow!

You can find my test project [in this github repository](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-28258270-video-in-oval-on-video/tree/master/video).

Comment: Rob this is amazing thanks so much. @BlaneTownsend hey I was wondering how to get the circle video once its made onto the screen, in view controller.m? Thanks

Comment: @iqueqiorio The [*AV Foundation Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1) has a whole chapter on playing videos,  and Apple has sample code and WWDC videos about it too.

Comment: great thanks rob. I have got my videos working now, but I am having some trouble making the inner oval the correct size I want to encapture the right amount of the inner vid. I would really appreciate it if you could spare a bit of time and help me, I invited you to a chat or my skype is spennyfontein. Thanks man

Comment: rob I could start a bounty if you like, I just need some help with the size?

Comment: I cannot promise to help you, but it sounds like you should post your own question.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind here is a link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448936/crop-video-into-circle-with-image-behind-it-in-ios

Comment: rob any chance you could help, i keep looking over your code but can't quite get it

Comment: Apple provides some sample code that implements `AVVideoCompositing` using OpenGL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This is great.  I'm attempting to modify it to work with videos of different lengths; specifically I'd like to loop the front video if it's shorter than the back video.  Any thoughts on how to do that?  All I can think of is to create a front asset that repeats until it is at least the length of the back asset, but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: I suspect you could use `-[AVMutableComposition insertTimeRange:ofTrack:atTime:error:]` to duplicate the contents of your shorter track as necessary. I don't have time to experiment with it.

Comment: @rob mayoff Do you think, we can implement this  effect without using customVideoCompositorClass but only using [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayers]?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Video overlay**

You have next options:

1. Add extra overlay(image, animation) using [`AVMutableVideoComposition. animationTool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablevideocomposition/1390395-animationtool). Actually it is a kind of post processing where extra overlay is added to your video

Add corners to video:

```
func applyCornersAsOverlayToComposition(
    composition: AVMutableVideoComposition,
    coverViewFrameSize: CGSize
) {
    //set up the parent layer
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    
    //apply corners
    parentLayer.masksToBounds = true
    parentLayer.cornerRadius = CollagePresenter.containerViewCornerRadius
    
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, coverViewFrameSize.width, coverViewFrameSize.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, coverViewFrameSize.width, coverViewFrameSize.height)
    
    //priority is important to make an overlay
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    
    let animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
    composition.animationTool = animationTool
}
```

2. Overlap multiple videos using [`AVMutableVideoComposition.instructions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablevideocomposition/1385815-instructions) and [`AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablevideocompositionlayerinstruction). It allows you to transform video (rotate, translate, scale...) and combine multiple of them

```
private func foo(
    videoAsset1: AVURLAsset,
    videoAsset2: AVURLAsset
) {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    let trackVideo1 = videoAsset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    let trackVideo2 = videoAsset2.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    
    let videoTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrack(
        withMediaType: .video,
        preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid
    )!
    
    let videoTrack2 = composition.addMutableTrack(
        withMediaType: .video,
        preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid
    )!
    
    try! videoTrack1.insertTimeRange(
        CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset1.duration),
        of: trackVideo1,
        at: CMTime.zero
    )
    
    try! videoTrack2.insertTimeRange(
        CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset2.duration),
        of: trackVideo1,
        at: CMTime.zero
    )
    
    let transform1 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0))
        .concatenating(
            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                0,
                0
            )
        )
    
    let transform2 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0))
        .concatenating(
            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                2,
                2
            )
        )
    
    let layerInstruction1 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack1)
    layerInstruction1.setTransform(
        transform1, at: CMTime.zero
    )
    
    let layerInstruction2 = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack2)
    layerInstruction2.setTransform(
        transform2, at: CMTime.zero
    )
    
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    
    //Max duration
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(
        start: CMTime.zero,
        duration: max(videoAsset1.duration, videoAsset2.duration)
    )
    
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction1, layerInstruction2]
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    
    videoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
}
```

3. Overlap multiple videos with custom instructions using [AVMutableVideoComposition.customVideoCompositorClass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablevideocomposition/1390649-customvideocompositorclass)

```
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)

//every frame processing
videoComposition.customVideoCompositorClass = CustomCompositor.self
let customOverlayInstruction = CustomOverlayInstruction(
    timeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(
        start: CMTime.zero,
        duration: videoAsset.duration
    ),
    videoEntries: videoEntries
)

videoComposition.instructions = [customOverlayInstruction]
```