# IOS video over video merge with circle cropping

Tags: ios, swift, video-processing, avvideocomposition

Iam making an app which does a basic video processing .
Ive successfully managed to merge to video (video over video) .
[image]
how can I crop the up-left small video into a circle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258270/how-to-crop-a-video-to-a-circle-in-ios
This might be of some help to you.

Comment: Ive looked at this before posting 
it doesnt confirm to AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction that I add to AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction

Answer (score 1):

If You want to export that video You need to:

1. Create `CALayer` which would be the parent of Your video layers
2. Add two `CALayer`s as sublayers of parent layer
3. Create a `CAShapeLayer` circle and mask the video layer you want
4. Create `AVMutableVideoComopsition` and setup it (`frameDuration`, `renderSize`, `instructions`, ... etc)
5. Create an `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` instance with `init(postProcessingAsVideoLayers:in:)` method
6. Assign it to `AVMutableVideoComopsition`'s `animationTool` property
7. Export it with `AVAssetExportSession` (with setting `AVMutableVideoComopsition` to property `videoCompostion` of export session)

This is only for post processing not for preview.

For preview You can try to create two `AVPlayerLayer`s with masking one of them, if this doesn't work You can create a custom video compositor and render each frame as you wish

Comment: How can we put videos in individual layers

Comment: @TalhaAhmadKhan while exporting? if yes then you need to look at `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` documentation. for example: https://medium.com/@dzungnguyen.hcm/add-overlay-image-to-video-21d9cc03c9eb . Its in Objective C, but I think it would not be a problem to translate it.

Comment: yes while exporting, but the link you gave shows us to overlay image instead I am interested in overlaying video on top of other video.

Comment: I will suggest to try with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositing .