# AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction setCropRectangle with ROTATED rectangle not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform, avmutablecomposition

I have a video that is placed at the origin of the screen, no rotation, as seen in this picture
(ignore the background):

[No crop rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sLvW.jpg)

I apply a basic rectangle (no rotation for now) crop with **setCropRectangle** so that it cuts my video in half, and displays the right side as you can see here:

[Crop Rectangle, no rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hoccy.jpg)

Now, I want to rotate my crop rectangle at 45 degrees. The test code I use looks something like this. I am just applying a rotating transform to my crop rectangle before I use it.

```
 let firstScale = CGFloat(0.8)
  let FirstlayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: firstTrack!)
  let Scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: firstScale, y: firstScale)
  let Move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
  let Rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
  FirstlayerInstruction.setTransform(Scale.concatenating(Rotation).concatenating(Move), at: .zero)


  let rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45.degreesToRadians).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: firstTrack!.naturalSize.width/2, y: 0))
  let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: firstTrack!.naturalSize.width/2, height: firstTrack!.naturalSize.height).applying(rectTransform)
  FirstlayerInstruction.setCropRectangle(rect, at: .zero)
```

This is just some test data. You can see I pass **45.degreesToRadians** as the rotation of the crop rectangle.

The result I get is not what I was expecting though:

[Actual Result + Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AhXW.jpg)

As you can see, the crop rectangle ignores rotation for some reason and keeps a larger, square form, instead of a diamond shape. The same applies for any rotation, negative values, 30, 60, etc. Anything I use for rotating the crop rectangle is not actually rotated.

Is the Core Graphics API limited to doing this? How can I achieve my expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not specify the angle of cropping. If you want to clip overlaid video, you have to create your own `class` implementing `AVVideoCompositing`   protocol, and assign it as `customVideoCompositorClass` property in your `AVMutableVideoComposition`. In this class you can specify a custom way of rendering resulting frame from source pixel buffers.
You can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260671/2051369

Comment: This actually does the trick. It's a very solid start to draw any shape using bezier paths. Thank you!